# adding an extra context while passing data to serializer django api

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add an extra field auth_token in my table with the `request.data` but it is giving errors. The error is -
`data['auth_token_id'] = auth_token
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

My code is given below:

serializers.py

```
class AppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
     model = ThirdPartyApps
     fields = ('app_name', 'package_name', 'auth_token_id')
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_apps(request):
    data = request.data
    auth_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHTOKEN', '')
    data['auth_token_id'] = auth_token
    serializer = AppSerializer(data=data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

I am looking for a way to pass extra data through the serializer.
I just want to add `auth_token` to my model like the `request.data` but it is giving this error -

`data['auth_token_id'] = auth_token
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should pass it as context like so:

serializers.py

```
class AppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    auth_token_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_auth_token_id(self, obj):
        if "auth_token_id" in self.context:
            return self.context["auth_token_id"]
        return None
    class Meta:
         model = ThirdPartyApps
         fields = ('app_name', 'package_name', 'auth_token_id')
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_apps(request):
    data = request.data
    auth_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHTOKEN', '')
    serializer = AppSerializer(data=data, many=True, context = {"auth_token_id": auth_token})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: and how will i save it ?

Comment: your answer is definitely accurate but how will i save tit to my table

Comment: If you wanted to save it, you would create a model (or use an existing one) and add a field to it, probably a `models.CharField(max_length = 254)` then set it `model.auth_token_id = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHTOKEN', '')` then `model.save()` in your views, or where you receive the auth token from.

Comment: but my friend i want to save it in auth_token_id field mentioned in the serializer fields with app_name and package_name.

Comment: Ahhh. Right. So you should get the model `a = ThirdPartyApps.objects.get(. . .)` then `a.auth_token_id = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHTOKEN', '')` then `a.save()` then there is no need to pass extra context.

Comment: did'nt get it bro.. in my views or serializer

Comment: @montudor could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039305/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-django-rest-framework-serializers? It is a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You can send the value also to the serializer's save method

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_apps(request):
    data = request.data
    auth_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHTOKEN', '')
    serializer = AppSerializer(data=data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(auth_token_id=auth_token)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

See docs here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save

Answer (score 0):

we can also use **class based** views like:

```
class AddApp(APIView):
      def post(request):
        data = request.data
        auth_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHTOKEN', '')
        serializer = AppSerializer(data=data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(auth_token_id=auth_token)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

also see an awesome tutorial about this topic [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/04/07/how-to-save-extra-data-to-a-django-rest-framework-serializer.html)