# How to pass extra context to Django Rest Framework serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

It is my first project using Django rest framework and i'm struggling to get this right. I know that in mainstream Django framework, if i need to add extra contexts to a class-based view, i will do something like this:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books by a certain author John
        context['john_books'] = Book.objects.filter(author=john)
        return context
```

then, i will be able to access the context 'john_books' in my template. Now i need to do same by passing extra contexts to my PostViewSets. On the detail view, i want to access the list of post authored by that post author in my api endpoint (something like 'Posts from the same author'). I have read about `get_serializer_context` but still can't figure out how to implement it. This is what i have so far:

```
class PostViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

     def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(PostViewSets, self).get_serializer_context()
        author = self.get_object.author
        author_posts = self.get_queryset().filter(author=author)
        context.update({'author_posts': author_posts})
        return context
```

i get this error:

> AttributeError at /posts/ 'function' object has no attribute 'author'

My Post Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    viewcount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and my PostSerializer class:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'body', 'author', 'viewcount', 'is_featured', 'created']
```

Comment: The answer by @ncopiy seems correct. It does not work because there are several issues and you may need to progress step by step and open new question for the new issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `get_object` as func, not as property:

```
class PostViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

     def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(PostViewSets, self).get_serializer_context()
        author = self.get_object().author
        author_posts = self.get_queryset().filter(author=author)
        context.update({'author_posts': author_posts})
        return context
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried that before and it gave assertion error

Comment: please find below the error:   `AssertionError at /posts/
Expected view PostViewSets to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the .lookup_field attribute on the view correctly`. However, the lookup_field attribute onn the viewset is set like so `lookup_field = 'pk'`

Comment: @banky how you call it?

Comment: @banky please add `lookup_field = 'pk'` parameter in `PostViewSets`

Comment: @banky please check if your URL looks like  /posts/<int:pk>

Comment: @M.Void yes. My typical URL is /posts/25/

Comment: @banky I mean in your `url.py `. Also, you can add `lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'` paramenter in `PostViewSets`

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. The Error Message

> AttributeError at /posts/ 'function' object has no attribute 'author'

explicitly explains what and where is the problem:

> author = self.get_object.author

I guess you tried to do something like this

```
author = self.get_object().author
```

#### 2. A DRF ViewSet

responses with data serialized by corresponding Serializer. So you don't need to change the ViewSet, but update the Serializer with something like:

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ... some fields ...

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [ ... some fields ... ]


class PostDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ... some fields ...

    author_posts = PostListSerializer(source="author.post_set", many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [ ... some fields ... , 'author_posts']
```

or with SerializerMethodField

```
    class PostDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ... some fields ...

    author_posts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author_posts(self, obj):
        return PostListSerializer(instance=obj.post_set.all(), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [ ... some fields ... , 'author_posts']
```

I didn't try this exact code, but this is the main idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass some context into serializers this way,

```
 serializer = self.serializer_class(instance=self.get_object(),
                                         context={'request': request}
                                        )
```